# Unity transform.LookAt() not updating with a moving target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

My camera casts a ray to the centre of the screen and I have an object that looks at that direction. The problem is, I made it such that certain keys rotate the camera, so there's a new centre, and the ray from the camera moves too but the object doesn't look at the new direction

Here's my code:

```
 void Update (){
 int x = Screen.width / 2;
 int y = Screen.height / 2;

 //Get centre of screen from camera
 Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (new Vector3 (x, y));
 Debug.DrawRay (ray.origin, ray.direction * 1000, new Color (1f, 0.922f, 0.016f, 1f));

 //Set object direction
 object.transform.LookAt (ray.direction);
 }
```

I'd really appreciate some help with this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Instead of looking at ray direction, I got a point from the ray using `GetPoint` and made the object look at that. It's working fine now.

Comment: Well, yes. `ray.direction` is a normalized direction vector, not a location.

Answer (score 0):

Well the ray would be starting from the camera and going towards the middle of the screen. So if you wanted the object to look at the camera every Update, the direction would be wrong, but also what if the object wasn't in the center of the screen? If I'm misinterpreting your question, please comment and explain further. I think a better way to get the forward direction of the camera would be to use `Camera.main.transform.forward`, and you could put that in a `Physics.Raycast` as well. To have something always look at the camera you could try `object.transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform.position, -Vector3.Up);`.

Edit: Also, if you mean the have the object look the same direction as the camera, you could always try `object.transform.forward = Camera.main.transform.forward`, or keep up with `object.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Camera.main.transform.forward, Transform.up);`

Alright **new idea:**

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5F, 0.5F, 0));
RaycastHit hit;
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
{
    Vector3 point = hit.point;
    object.transform.LookAt(point, Vector3.Up);
}
```

Comment: It's a sort of shooter game with a crosshair in the center of the screen so it always shoots the centre of the screen. When the camera moves or rotates,  of course the screen view moves too, so there's a new center, The ray from the camera moves to, always pointing to the center

Comment: My issue now is "object" is sort of a canon at an arbitrary position. "object" is what shoots ammo to the center of the screen

Comment: Got it. Try what I just edited to keep them looking the same direction. I wouldn't use Raycasts for this.

Comment: So it's just this canon at a different location than the camera, and when the fire button is pressed "object" fires ammo at the center of the screen. To achieve this, since camera has a ray pointing towards the center of the screen, I had "object" face that direction. There's a ray from object to, so the first time the game starts, the ray from object and the ray from camera intersect, which is what I wanted. My issue is that object remains facing that position and doesn't face a different direction when the camera does

Comment: You could (if I'm remembering how Unity works correctly) try making the object a child of the Camera, and resetting its transform to all 0. It _should_ then always have the same transform as the camera. You could even offset it a bit should you need.

Comment: Ohh, okay. I understand now. My answer probably won't work for that. Let me think about that for a second.

Comment: Aw damn, well check my updated solution anyway, hopefully it can help you in some way. It's in the original answer. It should keep the other object looking at the exact point the camera is looking at.